# What is the event type for FlatList's onScroll in react native?

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Typescript is complaining **Parameter 'event' implicitly has an 'any' type.** for the event in the onScroll function.

```
const onScroll = (event) => {
  console.log("width: ", event.nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement.width);
};

<FlatList
    data={data}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    onScroll={onScroll}
/>
```

Then I traced onScroll prop on the FlatList, found

```
/**
 * Fires at most once per frame during scrolling.
 * The frequency of the events can be contolled using the scrollEventThrottle prop.
 */
onScroll?: ((event: NativeSyntheticEvent<NativeScrollEvent>) => void) | undefined;
```

Then I updated the onScroll to the following, event type complaining is gone, but it's now complaining "**Property 'nativeEvent' does not exist on type 'NativeSyntheticEvent'**" for event.nativeEvent

```
const onScroll = (event: NativeSyntheticEvent<NativeScrollEvent>) => {
  console.log("width: ", event.nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement.width);
};
```

What is the event type for the onScroll's event parameter?

Comment: From [doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#onscroll) onScroll event has the following type: `{ nativeEvent: { contentInset: {bottom, left, right, top}, contentOffset: {x, y}, contentSize: {height, width}, layoutMeasurement: {height, width}, zoomScale }}`

Comment: yes, but is there a declared type for this definition?

Comment: Just tried what you did and I have no ts error. Are you sure you're importing both `NativeSyntheticEvent`and `NativeScrollEvent` from 'react-native'?

Comment: yes, I did imported NativeSyntheticEventand NativeScrollEvent from 'react-native'

Answer (score 0):

```js
import {
  ScrollView,
  NativeSyntheticEvent,
  NativeScrollEvent
} from 'react-native';

type OnScrollEventHandler = (event: NativeSyntheticEvent<NativeScrollEvent>) => void;

const MyComponent = () => {

    const onScroll: OnScrollEventHandler = (event) => {
      // do something here
    };

    return <ScrollView onScroll={onScroll}>
};
```

Comment: The code throws an error. Please use code blocks (`\`\`\``) instead of code sandboxes when there are errors occurring in the sandbox.

Comment: Im not sure what are you talking about.. but there is no sandbox, is just a portion of code. And of course this won't work, is intended to guide @s-hunter to solve the issue. hopefully

Comment: I mean, when I run the code, it throws an error. But it is up to you what method you want to use to show the code.

Comment: This still gives `Property 'nativeEvent' does not exist on type 'NativeSyntheticEvent<NativeScrollEvent>'` from typescript, when calling `event.nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement.width`

Comment: this code from below is working for me too so maybe try executing yarn or npm i
 and check if you are importing those right. Where ScrollView is coming from is from react native too?

```const onScroll = (event: NativeSyntheticEvent<NativeScrollEvent>) => {
  console.log("width: ", event.nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement.width);
};
```